# What are my options if i wanted to make an aol im bot in php?

Tags: php, aol

How would i make an aol aim bot in php, that is able to send and receive message, with a autoresponder. I have already taken a look at the toc protocol but wanted to use oscar if possible.

Comment: You mean as a program running on the user's machine, and not through a web page, right?

Comment: I mean as a script, maybe running thru a cron job, or yea as a page where it allow yu to send and receive is the idea to build off of, real simple tho.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak as to specific protocols, but the only architecture you can use for this is to have a daemon running on the server that holds the connection to the IM server open and logged in, and also has a channel/socket open on the server listening to PHP scripts that make a connection to it in order to send and receive messages.